# What kind of design style is this?

Tags: design-principles, style-identification, art

I found these images on Airbnb.com. Just out of curiosity, what's this kind of design work called? [image: Airbnb.com Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely modern, however the illustrations have been created to look a bit like old illustrations. London and Florence have clear Art Deco influences, AL, SF and Paris are more 50ies/60ies NYC Mad Men advertising. Tokyo doesn't look much like anything.